# Fsx execution path

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

I have a c# .net library I am looking to use within FSI/FSX. As part of the initialization of the .net lib, by default it expects and references a custom config file (MyAppConfig.xml) which loads various things before it can be used. When using it in c# it gets copied to the bin folder and the app by default expects it to be there and references it there unless there is a specific entry in the app.config to tell it otherwise. (I should add that it does it all by convention rather than injecting a path + filename, as per NLog, say)

I have an f# source file in a console app which will execute this initialization find, but I can't quite work out how to achieve this with FSI/FSX.

So my program.fs looks  simply like

```
open System
open myApp

module Program =   

    [<EntryPoint>]
    let Main(args) =            
        myApp.Initialization.Load()  // references MyAppConfig.xml

        Console.WriteLine("do my stuff!")
        Console.ReadLine() |> ignore
        0
```

If I try and do the same in FSI or using FSX, I have

```
#r @"E:\...path to MyApp...\MyApp.dll" 
#I @"E:\...path to MyAppConfig.xml ..."

Environment.CurrentDirectory <- @"E:\...path to MyAppConfig.xml ..."

myApp.Initialization.Load() |> ignore  // fails ... can't find MyAppConfig.xml

//do my stuff
```

I suspect that I've not got the paths quite right.

I'd be grateful of a steer

EDIT:

So I've managed to attach a debugger to the c# lib and see where it is looking for the config file - turns out it is "c:\Program Files\Microsoft F#\v4.0\" ( System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory) which again shows I've not quite understood how to tell FSI/FSX to use a particular path. If I copy the config file (MyAppConfig.xml) to that location it works fine.

Many thx

S

Comment: If you control the library in question, consider rewriting it so that it doesn't directly depend on the .config file. This is just one among several examples of how that's a poor design; other examples are: hard to vary configuration in unit tests; difficult to centralise configuration to an out-of-process database or service; difficult to make the configuration user-editable without security issues, etc. Obviously, if you don't control the library in question, this advice isn't particularly helpful...

Comment: Thx Mark ... unfortunately I don't have that control ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure of the implications, but one possiblity might be temporarily changing the app base:

```
let origAppBase = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("APPBASE", "path_to_MyAppConfig.xml")
myApp.Initialization.Load() |> ignore
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("APPBASE", origAppBase) //restore original app base
```

Comment: Thx vm Daniel. I've tried that and if I step it, the BaseDirectory still refers to "c:\Program Files\Microsoft F#\v4.0\" rather than the new AppBase. (FYI, I'm interactively executing each instruction.)